# train_auto() is not available in openCV CVKNearest

Tags: opencv, optimization, machine-learning, knn

I have used **train_auto()** method of **CVSvm** to optimize the parameters when I was using **SVM** .
Now I am using **k-nearest neighbours** algorithm so I searched for **train_auto()** method in CVKNearest. But It seems like train_auto() method is not available for **CVKNearest**.
Is it the case that instead of **train_auto()** method there's some other method that I need to use when optimizing the parameters with KNN. ?
 Actually, the only parameter is **K** and I need to get it optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically no training phase when using a KNN classifier, so there is no point in calling `train_auto`, neither in calling `train` at all in that case. 
KNN classifier outputs a label according to the labels of the closest descriptors, so it just needs to compute the K closests element. As to optimize K, you should try different values by cross validation to see what's best for your task

Comment: you mean to say by giving different values for K ? and the maximum value K can take is 35 and the minimum is 1 ...ryt ?

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question...the question is about KNN regression.

Comment: The minimum for K is 1 and the maximum is the number of data in your KNN model. In the case of regression, as said [in the doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html?highlight=knn#cvknearest-find-nearest), the value returned is the average value of the K nearest neighboors. I dont know if the average is weighted or not. Usually you'd want to try different strategies to compute regression estimates according to the labels/distances of the KNN